# Not able to telnet smtp server from google cloud vm

Tags: linux, smtp, google-compute-engine, mailgun

We have a account on `mailGun`.
we can ping and telnet to `smtp.mailgun.org` port `25` from our local system.

But when we use `google cloud vm` then

`ping smtp.mailgun.org` is successfull,
But `telnet smtp.mailgun.org 25` stucks at trying...

current firewall rules has `0.0.0.0/0 tcp:1-60000` entry in it.
`Iptables` are off.
OS: RHEL7

What might be wrong ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Google does not allow outbound connections on port 25 from Google cloud VM's:
https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/tutorials/sending-mail